# Jackson @JsonManagedReference on collection (one to many)

Tags: java, json, jackson, one-to-many

I have the following two classes.

`School` has many `TestTaker`s

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class School extends BaseModel {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "school")
    //    @JsonManagedReference <<<<< If not commented out, then error
    private Set<TestTaker> testTakers;
//getter setters
}

// TestTaker.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_taker")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class TestTaker extends BaseModel {
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    @JsonBackReference("school_testTaker")
    private School school;
//getters setters
}
```

Can anyone explain why @JsonManagedReference cannot be annotated on a collection? I would get an error saying Jackson cannot handle managed/back reference. How exactly does @JsonManagedReference work with @JsonBackReference in common DB relationships One-to-one, One-to-many, Many-to-one

I have read the documentation, still don't quite understand what Jackson is trying to achieve

Comment: I think the @JsonManagedReference above should have a matching param to the @JsonBackReference("school_testTaker"). So @JsonManagedReference("school_testTaker").